# Java: change the color of the shape when click on it by mouse

Tags: java, swing

In the below program, color of the shape is changed wherever mouse click on the panel or frame. But i want to change the color only if mouse is clicked on that shape. Is there any way to do this without using location?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*;

public class Colorchange extends JFrame {

    public Colorchange() {
        setTitle("Change Color on click");
        setSize(500,500);
        MyPanel pane=new MyPanel();
        add(pane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Colorchange ob=new Colorchange();
        ob.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ob.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    int x=200,y=200,r=50;
    Color co=Color.RED;

    public MyPanel() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                co=Color.YELLOW;
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(co);
        g.fillOval(x-r, y-r, 2*r, 2*r);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i want to change the color of a shape if the mouse is clicked on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the x,y position of the cursor before repaint

```
//...
public MyPanel() {
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            if(me.getX() >= (x-r) && me.getX() < (x+r) && me.getY() >= (y-r) && me.getY() < (y+r)) {
                co=Color.YELLOW;
                repaint();
            }
        }
    });
}
//...
```

Comment: Dont worry (but upvoting is apreciated;)) Also, you can simplify and generalise the code using the Rectangle class and the method contains(x, y)

Comment: sorry i join yesterday only. i don't have 15 reputation to upvoting for u.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a object of that shape.
Add locations to the object.
OnMouseClick, check if the mouse locations equals the shape locations.

Good luck with it.

Comment: Thanks. I will try. Is there any other way without using location?

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Comment: @Rajagopal Yes, but to be frank, why would you bother reinventing the wheel when an API already exist which will not only achieve the mouse click detection, but also paint the shape as well..